# Dynamically add and remove items in multiple places in Vue

Tags: algorithm, vue.js

I have a page written in Vue, where there is a table with 3 columns as shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox7gn.png

Each column is a whole entity, and each row are the properties of the entities.

At the bottom of each column, there is a group of buttons for each column.

What I want to do is to append some additional attributes (strings) to possibly more than one properties of an entity when a button is clicked, like below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnUzt.png

And when another button is clicked, more strings are appended.

When a button is clicked again, the corresponding properties will be removed. For example, if the "a" button in the second image was clicked, the table will revert to the first image.

Since there are many properties (around 10), I don't want to hard code all the strings as div's under each and every property and render them conditionally using v-show/v-if.

I have also thought about storing an array of the number of active buttons and re-render the whole table when any button is clicked. (The reason why the whole table has to be re-rendered is because each individual rows are rendered with a for-loop, so I cannot just modify a single element in a row.) But this does not seem very natural, and I believe there should be a better solution.

Is there a good way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a working example?

Comment: Yes. For each cell that could be changed, add all the possible strings to be added and display them conditionally: <div v-if="a">stringa</div><div v-if="b">stringb</div><div v-if="c">stringc</div> and so on. But that would be very redundant.